# ECS Fargate - Request Forwarding to Tasks

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, aws-application-load-balancer, ecs-taskdefinition

Can we setup any rule in which we forward our incoming request to specific task on which more memory and space available compare to another task.

For example: I have one service and there are 2 task attached to it. Request are coming to service and it is forwarding request to tasks. Sometimes it forward to task 1 and sometimes it forward request to task 2. The issue is it sometimes forward the request to task on which already many processes are running. It do not forward the request to other on which there is no process running on it. I want to control that if memory and cpu of one task is high then forcefully forward my request to another task on which more memory and cpu available. In short I want to control request forwarding.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an AWS load balancer, there isn't any way to do this because you can use only the algorithms defined by the load balancer (round robin or least outstanding requests); the load balancer doesn't have visibility into container resource utilization.